# TypeScript conditional return type based on return value?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have this code:

```js
type SuccessResponse = {
  success: true;
  image: string;
};

type FailResponse = {
  success: false;
  message: string;
};

type OpenGraphScraperResponse = SuccessResponse | FailResponse;

export const useOpenGraphScraper = (text: string, guid: string) => {
  return useQuery<OpenGraphScraperResponse>(['og', guid], () => {
    return axios.get(`/api/open-graph-scraper?content=${text}`).then((res) => {
      if (res.data.success) {
        return res.data as SuccessResponse;
      }

      return res.data as FailResponse;
    });
  });
};
```

I like the return type to be `SuccessResponse` whenever the data returned contains `success: true` and `FailResponse` whenever it's `success: false`.

In my template, I want to access the `image` property so I did it like this:

```html
<div v-if="result.success">
    <img :src="result.image" />
</div>
```

Even though I wrapped it inside a condition where it should only render the img element when `success: true`, TypeScript still complains:

```
Property 'image' does not exist on type 'SuccessResponse | FailResponse'.
  Property 'image' does not exist on type 'FailResponse'.
```

Comment: I think your problem is with vue, not with typescript

Comment: you don't have image on FailResponse response so  <img :src="result.image as SuccessResponse" /> or create successResponse = result as SuccessResponse and then use it.

Comment: What is the setup to allow TS in templates? It obviously doesn't consider `v-if` a type guard.

Comment: My advice is seperate data and failResponse or create a type that is combination of them. Like  `{ succes:boolean; image?:string; message?:stiring; }` and return an object that fits that type